# Auto Layout constraint breaks when condition changes in table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

In my tableView Cell, I have an array of strings from API which I uses to determine the height of a stackview based on the amount of array elements. The array can have 3, 4 or X number of elements.

```
var pollDataInPollCell: PollModel? {
        didSet{
            if let pollOptions = pollDataInPollCell?.poll_detail{
                // pollOptions = ["A", "B"] or ["A", "XS", "XSMAX"]

           optionBtnStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(30 * pollOptions.count).isActive = true
}
var optionBtnStackView: UIStackView = {
   let sv = UIStackView()
    sv.axis = .vertical
    sv.distribution = .fillEqually
    return sv
}()
```

Everything works great at launch. The stackView height for each row looks perfect and there is no constraint breaking. However, if I scroll up and down the tableView, my stackView height isn't the same anymore and I believe it is due to tableView dequeueReusableCell. My question is if it is possible to reset my stackView height in didSet so that it can render new height. I have tried this in didSet

```
optionBtnStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
optionBtnStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(30 * pollOptions.count).isActive = true
```

or

```
optionBtnStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(30 * pollOptions.count).isActive = false
optionBtnStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(30 * pollOptions.count).isActive = true
```

but both don't solve my problem. Any suggestions? Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot to explain what exactly you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you are just adding new constraints to the old ones, and then they just collide.

This line:

```
optionBtnStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(30 * pollOptions.count)).isActive = true
```

creates and activates a **new** constraint. If you call the same line again with different data, a new constraint is added with a different height, and then they collide.

Solution should be pretty easy and simple. First create a property and keep a reference to a single one constraint. Then, when setting data, just update the constant, and do not create a new constraint.

E.g., something like:

```
fileprivate var stackHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

var pollDataInPollCell: PollModel? {
    didSet {
        if let pollOptions = pollDataInPollCell?.poll_detail {
            // lazily initialized heightConstraint:
            if stackHeightConstraint == nil {
                // this creates the constraint and keeps a reference to it
                stackHeightConstraint = optionBtnStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(30 * pollOptions.count))
                // and we can activate it properly
                stackHeightConstraint?.isActive = true
            } else {
                // here the stackHeightConstraint is initialized, so just set the constant
                stackHeightConstraint?.constant = CGFloat(30 * pollOptions.count)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem still exists when I scroll up and down. This is the error that I receive
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000029b7930 UIStackView:0x7fa6ee53ddb0.height == 120   (active)>

Comment: Also, if I use constant value such as 30 instead of pollOptions.count, my constraint wont break. Unfortunately, I have to reply on pollOptions.count to set the height for stackview.

Comment: @NancyP can you share more of your code? ideally the whole part that handles the view/layout of the given cell